# Swift type conversion example but using a class

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to programming and I'm following a tutorial for fun to understand things in more detail.  The tutorial I'm reading creates code that takes a Double and a Int type and multiply them.  As we all know, they converted the Int to a Double to perform the operation.  Here is the example code:

```
let hourlyRate: Double = 19.5
let hoursWorked: Int = 10
let totalCost: Double = hourlyRate * Double(hoursWorked)
```

After seeing this I said okay cool so let me see if I can do that in a passion project I'm working on.  In the passion project code I use a UIStoryboard method that returns a UIViewController so I thought it would be interesting if I could do the same as the tutorial with my variable called controller in the following code:

```
class ItemListDataProviderTests: XCTestCase {

    var controller: ItemListViewController!
    var sut: ItemListDataProvider!
    var tableView: UITableView!


    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        sut = ItemListDataProvider()

        sut.itemManager = ItemManager()

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ItemListViewController") as! ItemListViewController //compiles

        controller = ItemListViewController(storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ItemListViewController")) //causes error and code doesn't compile

        _ = controller.view

        tableView = controller.tableView

        tableView.dataSource = sut

    }
```

As you can see it didn't work out the way I hoped.  I felt type casting was an extra step but I see that its necessary to make the code compile but I don't understand WHY that wouldn't work.  What does the computer think I'm asking it to do which makes it not understand?  I really want to know and understand why so any help is greatly greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double has an init method that takes an Int as an argument so you can write Double(intValue). You cannot do that with the ViewController classes above because there is no init that takes the other type, and in fact you do not want to create a new instance, you want to say 'this instance is actually this type', and you use 'as' for that.

Answer (score 3):

With this line of code :

```
ItemListViewController(storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ItemListViewController"))
```

you're trying to pass an argument of UIViewController into a constructor of ItemListViewController.  No such constructor exists.

Also, by instantiating the view controller from the storyboard, you are given an instance of that view controller that's already loaded into memory. So there would be no need to instantiate another as you are doing

The correct way instead is to use the as! operator as you are doing on the line before.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `controller = ItemListViewController(storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ItemListViewController"))`, but this is both wrong and unnecessary.  In the line just above you correctly instantiate the viewController and assign it to the `controller` variable.  On this line you appear to be trying to do the exact same thing again, but in a different way.  The reason it's failing is that I assume you don't have an initializer for `ItemListViewController` that takes a `UIViewController` as the only argument, which is what you're asking it to do.  If I'm wrong, please post the code for that initializer so we can analyze.  Either way, that line is completely unnecessary.  Delete it and your code should compile.